# Confusion of Assembly and hardware level memory fetching, processing, segmentation, offsets, scope of memory addressing, etc

Tags: performance

I am very perplexed having studied Assembly for some time, and reviewing many great tutorials on it.

It is surprisingly difficult I must say to fully understand the whole scheme of its usefulness, aside from memorizing a few instructions to do some things you don't completely understand.

I seek to be an operating system developer and designer, so I have to know low-level hardware data processing, memory management, processor fetching, decoding, and memory segmentation, memory usage, bit and byte usage, call stack and hardware stacks, and the mechanics of a machine-level program from the hardware itself.

Here are my main questions I am confused about:

The processor fetches bytes from RAM. When writing a bootloader you "jump" to an address before writing instructions. The first instruction executed after jumping to the address in memory, such as a move/data copy `MOV AL, MOV BL` kind of instruction retrieves data on the CPU's pipeline which is not directly used in memory. But how can the processor generate a code data segment on its pipeline if the instruction is loaded/fetched from memory? Or do I have it all wrong here? What is the basic steps the microprocessor does in a bootloader, and how does the CPU generate code data from a pipeline without using memory if instructions are all fetched from memory supposedly(e.g. code segments in Assembly, but data segments and text segments are all instructions for the processor)?

Also, my next main question is probably very easy to answer for some more experienced than me:

Why is memory/RAM on x86 and other architectures stored as "segments" with offsets? To me this is more complex than it needs to be. Why can't all memory be linear, addressed, fetched, stored, and computed, and moved in and out of the registers to the memory cells in a more straightforward manner? Would that not make the illustration and understanding of the architecture easier to understand, and more direct than having multitudes of registers process bi-dimensional segmentations of memory-based data storage and accessing?

Answer (score 0):

It's more than "assembly" vs "high level language".

The real issue is "Real" vs. "Protected" (virtual memory) modes.

And unfortunately, most x86 assembly examples happen to be *DOS* examples.  Which, IMHO, have little/no relevance to contemporary 32/64 bit virtual memory architectures (including, but not limited to, x86).

Excellent primer:

[Programming from the Ground Up](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/pgubook/)

PS:
Address space *is* effectively linear, event for x86, on most modern OS's (including Windows, Linux and Mac OS).  x86 segment registers are largely anachronisms from the DOS era.

If you're interested, here's a good overview of the Linux boot process:

- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-linuxboot/index.html

Comment: But the concept, unfortunately, of "Real" versus "Protected" modes, or virtual memory in general has nothing to do with the actual implementation of data processing that the CPU does with real memory (no virtual implementation) directly. What I want to know is how I should understand the data processing, and how I can use the best of that knowledge to really know what my code is doing, and how I'd be implementing the code, data, and segments of memory and processing at that level. A DOS x86 example is useless because Disk Operating System operations are in particular with that operating system

Comment: What I want is the full scoop of it from an unbiased viewpoint(e.g. a Disk Operating System and Linux-based boot-up is specific to that OS, and does not overview the basic concept of a memory address, instruction decoding, and system processing design implementation).

Comment: Q: "But the concept, unfortunately, of "Real" versus "Protected" modes, or virtual memory in general has nothing to do with the actual implementation of data processing that the CPU does with real memory (no virtual implementation) directly."  A: That's flat-out wrong.  "Virtual Memory" is a "hardware thing". The CPU loads, stores and manipulates the *same* virtual addresses seen by the process (or by the kernel).  Read PGU - I honestly think you'll enjoy it :)

Comment: But at the time being I simply want to understand it without the confuaion of virtual memory, and that site you gave is unclear.

Comment: Dude - it's not "confusion".  It's *fundamental*.  For contemporary systems, you simply cannot understand the concept of "memory access" without also grasping the different between "physical" and "virtual" addresses.  And, for that matter, memory-mapped IO too.  Honest :)  IMHO...